# pushing array inside array perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

**edited:**

How can I push @myarr into $menu (see below)

```
my @myarr = (
                [ "itemone", "itemoneb", "itemonec" ],
                [ "itemtwo", "itemtwob", "itemtwoc" ],
                [ "itemthree", "itemthewwb", "itemthreec" ],
                [ "itemfour", "itemfourb", "itemfourc" ]
               );

$menu = [
         "List",
         ["itemone", \&ds2],
         ["itemtwo", \&ds2],
         ["itemthree", \&ds2],
         ["itemfour", \&ds2],
         [ "Do Something (second)", \&ds2 ]
     ];
```

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results? Shouldn't be not that hard after reading [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut). :)

Comment: are you trying to push "itemoneb" and "itemonec" into the existing arrayref holding "itemone"?  and what is `&ds2`?

Comment: Why is this closed as not a real question. It's perfectly clear what the question is.

Answer (score 8):

This depends on what exactly you want to do.

You can either directly push the array:

```
push (@$menu, @myarr);

#results in:

[
     "List",
     ["itemone", \&ds2],
     ["itemtwo", \&ds2],
     ["itemthree", \&ds2],
     ["itemfour", \&ds2],
     [ "Do Something (second)", \&ds2 ],
     [ "itemone", "itemoneb", "itemonec" ],
     [ "itemtwo", "itemtwob", "itemtwoc" ],
     [ "itemthree", "itemthewwb", "itemthreec" ],
     [ "itemfour", "itemfourb", "itemfourc" ]
];
```

which results in the `myarr` *elements* being pushed to `menu`, or push the reference:

```
push (@$menu, \@myarr);

#results in:

[
     "List",
     ["itemone", \&ds2],
     ["itemtwo", \&ds2],
     ["itemthree", \&ds2],
     ["itemfour", \&ds2],
     [ "Do Something (second)", \&ds2 ],
     [
        [ "itemone", "itemoneb", "itemonec" ],
        [ "itemtwo", "itemtwob", "itemtwoc" ],
        [ "itemthree", "itemthewwb", "itemthreec" ],
        [ "itemfour", "itemfourb", "itemfourc" ],
     ],
];
```

which actually pushes the array (nested array).

Answer (score 4):

You can just push it:

```
 use Data::Dumper;
 push (@$menu, @myarr);
 print Dumper($menu), "\n";
```

Comment: this pushes elements of `@myarr` into `@$menu`, to push an array push its reference `push $@menu,\@myarr`